# passing arguments with an array based object method call

Tags: php, oop, object, methods

I need to call a method from within a function, so I must pass it as an array like so:

```
array($this, 'display_page');
```

but I need to pass arguments along with it. Is this possible?

**EDIT** - *New Method* - *Still not working.*

I have now tried passing an anonymous function, in place of the array call back.

```
function(){MyClass::display_page($display);}
```

and edited the function thusly:

```
class MyClass{

static function display_page($arg = false)
    {
      if($arg){
        echo $arg;
      } else {
        echo "Nothing to report!";
      }
     }
}
```

but all I get is **Nothing to report!**

**EDIT** The problem lies with the way the callback was being used within Wordpress (didn't think it was relevant, turns out it was). Have voted to close.

Comment: Please clarify. You need to pass arguments along with the callback function reference? That's... unusual.

Comment: You don't need to use `&` in PHP for a callback of an object method.

Comment: @deceze yes, it's either that or write several different callbacks where only one line changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a look at [call_user_func](https://www.php.net/call_user_func%27), you can see that it has a second optional parameter called parameter.

```
mixed call_user_func ( callback $function [, mixed $parameter [, mixed $... ]] )
```

Use that.

Or you could do it the dirty way like mentioned in [the comment on call_user_func](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php#99870)

```
$method_name = "AMethodName";
$obj = new ClassName();
$obj->{$method_name}();
```

Comment: This method doesn't work as it calls the function, rather than passing a reference to it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something along these lines will do:

```
class Foo {

    public function callMe() {
        $args = func_get_args();
        var_dump($args);
    }

    public function getCallback() {
        $that = $this;
        return function ($oneMoreArg) use ($that) {
            $that->callMe(1, 2, $oneMoreArg);
        };
    }

}

$foo = new Foo;
$callback = $foo->getCallback();
$callback(3);
```

If you're not running PHP 5.3, the best you can do is probably return a "custom callback array" and "custom call it":

```
$callback = array($this, 'callMe', 1, 2);

$args = array_splice($callback, 2);
$args[] = 3;
call_user_func_array($callback, $args);
```